# Case Class and Implicit Arguments and Pattern Matching

Tags: scala

I tried to combine implicit arguments with case classes, but I got stuck.

```
case class C(i: Int)(implicit b: Boolean)
val c1 = C(1)(true)
implicit val b = true
val c2 = C(2)
c1 match {
  case C(i)(b) => // doesn´t work
  case C(i,b)  => // doesn´t work
  case C(i)    => // works, but wanted: if (b) i else 0 
}
```

According to the Scala Language Specification it´s due to the compiler generated extractor object for case classes: My implicit `Boolean` is not a member of the resulting case class, so it has to be in the second (implicit) argument list (that I can´t find in the companion object´s apply method, unfortunately):

> A case class definition of `c[tps](ps1 ). . .(psn)` with type parameters `tps` and value
>   parameters `ps` implicitly generates an extractor object (§8.1.8) which is defined as
>   follows:

```
object c {
  def apply[tps](ps1 ). . .(psn): c[tps] = new c[Ts](xs1 ). . .(xsn)
  def unapply[tps](x: c[tps]) =
    if (x eq null) scala.None
    else scala.Some(x.xs11, . . . , x.xs1k)
}
```

How can I define a case class with members that are implicitly supplied at creation time?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can *define* a case class with implicit arguments, but as you've discovered, they're not available for pattern matching.  You could always write your own extractor though:

```
case class C(i: Int)(implicit val b: Boolean)

// You can't call this C because that seat is taken (can't overload the default unapply)
object C_ { 
  // In order to be able to select `b` here, 
  // it needs to be declared as "implicit *val* b: Boolean"
  def unapply(in: C) = Some((in.i, in.b)) 
}

c1 match {
  case C_(i, b) => ...
}
```

Comment: Actually I think you *can* define `object C` to override the case-class supplied `unapply`.  Also `implicit b` is not automatically turned into `val b` so there's some further work.

Comment: "Cannot resolve overloaded unapply" :)  And as for the val, yep, I was mid-edit. :)

Comment: I suppose then, you could equally write: `c1 match { case x @ C(i) => if (x.b) i else 0 }`

Answer (score 6):

Alex's answer is clever, however I don't really like the `_` in the object name, I find the syntax a little strange and remembering the underscore makes pattern matching more difficult to use.  (Of course this is all subjective so your feelings may vary).

My first approach to dealing with this were to move the implicit parameters to the `apply` method in the companion object.

```
case class A(i: Int, b: Boolean)

object Foo {
  def apply(i: Int)(implicit b: Boolean): Foo = apply(a, b)
}
```

But this results in

```
Error:(21, 14) double definition: 
method apply:(i: Int, b: Boolean)com.workday.cloud.master.package.A and 
method apply:(i: Int)(implicit b: Boolean)com.workday.cloud.master.package.A at line 24 
have same type after erasure: (i: Int, b: Boolean)com.workday.cloud.master.package.A   
  case class A(i: Int, b: Boolean)
             ^
```

We can fix this by adding an extra unused implicit parameter.

```
object A {
  def apply(i: Int)(implicit b: Boolean, unused: DummyImplicit): A = apply(i, b)
}
```

Which approach you choose is up to you, I find this approach enables my client code to look more natural.

Comment: You could use DummyImplicit instead of Unused object to be more regular i suppose.
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/DummyImplicit.html

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about that object.